# Variable in handler not being reassigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a boolean variable and two buttons on my page. The boolean variable is assigned to ture on page load and it should switch between true and false when I click Button A and Button B and alert ture when Button A is clicked and alert false when Button B is clicked. The problem with my code is it is alerting true no matter which button is clicked. I can put the alert inside onclick function but I don't want to do it. I want to use boolean variable.

Here is code.

```
<div><button type="button" id="btnA">Button A</button></div>
<div><button type="button" id="btnB">Button B</button></div>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var value = true;
        $('#btnA').click(function(){
        var value = true;
        myFunction();
        });
        $('#btnB').click(function(){
        var value = false;
        myFunction();
        });
        function myFunction(){
        if (value == true){
            alert('true');
        }else{
            alert('false');
        }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you're having a scope problem because you have `var value` within all of your functions except the last. just use it the first time. after that, just use `value =` without `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reinitializing your variables every time. Just use 'var' the first time you set 'value' but not the other times.

```
var value = true;
$('#btnA').click(function(){
  value = true;
myFunction();
});
$('#btnB').click(function(){
 value = false;
myFunction();
});
function myFunction(){
if (value == true){
    alert('true');
}else{
    alert('false');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring new variable on every call. What you need is to change the value of the existing one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var value = true;
        $('#btnA').click(function(){
        value = true; //no var keyword
        myFunction();
        });
        $('#btnB').click(function(){
        value = false; //no var keyword
        myFunction();
        });
        function myFunction(){
        if (value == true){
            alert('true');
        }else{
            alert('false');
        }
        }
    });
```

And btw `if( smth == true)` can be replaced in your case with `if(smth)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `value` to function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var value = true;
        $('#btnA').click(function(){
        var value = true;
        myFunction(value);
        });
        $('#btnB').click(function(){
        var value = false;
        myFunction(value);
        });
        function myFunction(value){
        if (value == true){
            alert('true');
        }else{
            alert('false');
        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope problem.  You are defining 'value'. (i.e. var-ing it) in your function.

Drop the var key word.